# How does Python 2.7.3 hash strings used to seed random number generators?

Tags: python, python-2.7, random

In 64 bit Python 2.7.6 this is True, however in 32 bit Python 2.7.3 it is False:

```
random.Random(hash("a")).random() == random.Random("a").random()
```

So how does Python 2.7.3 hash strings used to seed random number generators?

Comment: Python *is* open source - you can just read the code.

Comment: Also, it would help to also try it in 32-bit Python 2.7.6 and 64-bit Python 2.7.3 to narrow down whether the difference is between 2.7.3 and 2.7.6 or 32-bit and 64-bit. And what operating system is this?

Comment: I suspect it varies both between platforms and build architectures, but also between specific strings. Assuming Python's `hash` is well distributed, it should work for about half of the objects you try it with and fail for half.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

it's because on 32bit `hash("a")` is a negative number (because of platform long type size) and the random modules behaves differently.

The random module seed() function:

- passing int or long it will use `PyNumber_Absolute()` that is `abs()`
- passing an object (a string) it will use `PyLong_FromUnsignedLong((unsigned long)hash)`

sign bit truncation and abs give different result

e.g.:

- `abs(-10) = 10`
- `((unsigned long) -10) = 4294967286`

Comment: This is the right answer. It's worth noting that [a comment above the code that does this](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/0c8a7299c7e3/Modules/_randommodule.c#l231) in Python 2 incorrectly says that it takes the absolute value in both cases. In Python 3, [the comment has been fixed](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/e159cb0d955b/Modules/_randommodule.c#l228) to correctly describe what it does for non-integers (casting the signed hash value to an unsigned one, which is equivalent to adding `sys.maxsize` to any negative values).